# Reading all lines in a file providing a relative path in .NET (F#)

Tags: .net, file-io, f#, filesystems

I am looking for a method (I guess it  is a static method) in the .NET libraries to let me specify a relative path when reading a file.
My code is:

```
let mycontent = Syste..IO.File.ReadAllLines ("C:\...\myfile.txt")
```

However I would like to specify a relative path. How to? It is some sort of `MapPath` I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want paths relative to the directory in which your application resides (as opposed to the current working directory, which may be different), you can do the following:

```
module Path =
    let appDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
    let makeAppRelative fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, fileName)

//Usage
let fullPath = Path.makeAppRelative "myfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 5):

A relative path is specified like this:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");
```

which will search `myfile.txt` relative to the working directory executing your application. It works also with subfolders:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"sub\myfile.txt");
```

The `MapPath` function you are referring to in your question is used in ASP.NET applications and allows you to retrieve the absolute path of a file given it's virtual path. For example:

```
Server.MapPath("~/foo/myfile.txt")
```

and if your site is hosted in `c:\wwwroot\mysite` it will return `c:\wwwroot\mysite\foo\myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a relative path to any function that accepts a file path, and it will work fine.

Comment: My advice is to never, never do this.  This uses the current working directory, which is a global variable that any other code in the process can (and often will) change willy-nilly, on background threads, etc.  Danger!  I've gotten so bitten by this I've actually written wrappers around the .NET APIs that assert if the path is non-absolute, just to ensure I'm never depending on the global state.

Comment: @Brian: Yes; it's usually bad idea, but it seems to be exactly what he wants to do.  Presumably, he's aware of these issues.